# HtmlAgilityPack C#--- Selectnodes Always returns a Null

Tags: c#, xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

This is the xpath text i tried to use along with HtmlAgilityPack C# parser.

```
//div[@id = 'sc1']/table/tbody/tr/td/span[@class='blacktxt']
```

I tried to evaluate the xpath expression with firefox xpath add=on and sucessfully got the required items. But the c# code returns an Null exception.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection node = htmldoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id ='sc1']/table/tbody/tr/td/span[@class='blacktxt']");            
MessageBox.Show(node.ToString());
```

the node always contains null value...
Please help me to find the way to get around this problem...
Thank you..

Comment: Looking at the source you get from the network (Html Agility Pack) and the source a browser displays are two potentially very different things as a browser can execute javascript which modifies the source/DOM. Tell us what source you have and what do you search and we may tell you how to make it work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does my XPath query (scraping HTML tables) only work in Firebug, but not the application I'm developing?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18241029/why-does-my-xpath-query-scraping-html-tables-only-work-in-firebug-but-not-the)

Answer (score 0):

### DOM Requires `<tbody/>` Tags to be Inserted

All common browser extensions for building XPath expressions work on the DOM. Opposite to the HTML specs, the DOM specs require `<tr/>` elements to be inside `<tbody/>` elements, so browsers add such elements if missing. You can easily see the difference if looking at the HTML source using Firebug (or similar developer tools working on the DOM) versus displaying the page source (using `wget` or similar tools that do not interpret anything if necessary).

### The Solution

Remove the `/tbody` axis step, and your XPath expression will probably work.

```
//div[@id = 'sc1']/table/tr/td/span[@class='blacktxt']
```

### If you Need to Support Both HTML With and Without `<tbody/>` Tags

For a more general solution, you could replace the `/tbody` axis step by a decendant-or-self step `//`, but this could jump into "inner tables":

```
//div[@id = 'sc1']/table//tr/td/span[@class='blacktxt']
```

Better would be to use alternative XPath expressions:

```
//div[@id = 'sc1']/table/tr/td/span[@class='blacktxt'] | //div[@id = 'sc1']/table/tbody/tr/td/span[@class='blacktxt']
```

A cleaner XPath 2.0 only solution would be

```
//div[@id = 'sc1']/table/(tbody, self::*)/tr/td/span[@class='blacktxt']
```